# How to detect if property changed in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have simple class which looks like this:

```
export class MessagesPage  {

    @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

    public message  = '';
    public messages = [];

    public state = 'general';
}
```

Is it possible inside the class to detect if `state` property is changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make them getters and setters. There is no other way to get notified about changes:

```
export class MessagesPage  {

    @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

    public message  = '';
    public messages = [];

    private _state = 'general';
    public get state() { return this._state; }
    public set state(value:string) { 
      this._state = value;
      console.log('state changed', this._state);
    }
}
```