# Angular 4 import isPropertyUpdated method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to use `isPropertyUpdated` in Angular 4, but Angular 4 doesn't support deep imports.

So this import doesn't work on angular 4 :

```
import {isPropertyUpdated} from  'angular2/src/common/forms/directives/shared'
```

So what can I do, to use `isPropertyUpdated` on Angular 4?

Comment: this method is not public so it's not exposed in `@angular/forms` package. importing it from the internal packages is risky

Comment: To detect property changes, see this answer from @Günter Zöchbauer earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45477825/1791913

Comment: Damn, I can't access this._state on the controller, using my if like this, will solve my issue: if (isPropertyUpdated(changes, this.lastViewModel)) {}

Answer (score 0):

If you really need this you can read the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts) and decide if this is overkill for what you need. I would think `ngOnChanges()` would suit most needs.

In your project add something like this:

```
import { elooseIdentical } from '@angular/core';

export function isPropertyUpdated(changes: {[key: string]: any}, viewModel: any): boolean {
  if (!changes.hasOwnProperty('model')) return false;
  const change = changes['model'];

  if (change.isFirstChange()) return true;
  return !elooseIdentical(viewModel, change.currentValue);
}
```

Comment: I'm only using for a verification, like this : ngOnChanges(changes) {
 
  if (isPropertyUpdated(changes, this.lastViewModel)) {
   this.lastViewModel = this.model
   this.refreshView()
  }
 }